# What does this old PHP code mean - variable name on a single line?

Tags: php

I'm re-factoring this ugly pile of legacy code and I came across this:

```
// $log is a PEAR logging object 
$log->debug( 'some error message' );
```

with this immediately after:

```
$foo;
$bar;
...
...
```

I.e. Just a load of variable names within a function.. what does this do ?  Nothing ?

Thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're completely pointless and they don't declare the variables at all, as PHP has no concept of variable declaration, only assignment, and these statements don't assign anything to the variables. See [an example using `$variable;`](http://codepad.org/EpOJTKmi) as compared to [this example without `$variable;`](http://codepad.org/Bp1w9AqG); they have the same result.

Perhaps it's a coding style.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm 99.999% sure they're no-ops. Even with PHP, even with some awful `__get` and whatnot... they couldn't do anything. I hope.

Answer (score 2):

They are variable declarations without values being assigned to them.

Comment: well technically they have a value of `null`

Comment: If @fire is correct then isset() will be false QUOTE: __Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.__ http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php